# How to use omni_getbalance

Tags: bitcoin

I try to run `omni_getbalance` to check the balance of specific address, for example:`./omnicore-0.3.0/bin/omnicore-cli omni_getbalance 1G47mSr3oANXMafVrR8UC4pzV7FEAzo3r9 31`,always return 0.
the version of omnicore is 0.3.0, downloaded from this link: [omnicore-0.3.0-x86_64-linux-gnu.tar.gz](https://github.com/OmniLayer/omnicore/releases/download/v0.3.0/omnicore-0.3.0-x86_64-linux-gnu.tar.gz), can someone tell me why? thanks a lot.

Answer (score -1):

`omni_getbalance` can't return any address balance except those belonging to the wallet of the omni node.